# LINQ inner join for nested list

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have a Model:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid CategoryID { get; set; }
    public List<Guid> Tags { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
public class Tag
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

I have a ModelRepository of Model objects. I have VieModels:

```
public class TransactionViewModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }       
    public CategoryViewModel Category { get; set; }
    public List<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }        
}
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
public class TagViewModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to make `List<TransactionViewModel>` from `List <Transaction>` using linq. How did I:

```
VM.Categories = ModelRepository.Categories.Select(p => new CategoryViewModel(p)));
VM.Tags = ModelRepository.Tags.Select(p => new TagViewModel(p)));

var trans = from t in ModelRepository.Transactions
            join c in VM.Categories on t.CategoryID equals c.ID
            select new TransactionViewModel()
            {
              ...,
              Category = c
            };
VM.Transactions = trans.ToList();
```

Now when I change any `CategoryViewModel` in `VM.Categories`, I immediately get changes for all `TransactionViewModel.Category` in `VM.Transactions`. Question - how do I fill `TransactionViewModel.Tags`? Preferably with LINQ. And it's mandatory that when changing any `TagViewModel` in `VM.Tags`, I immediately get changes for all `TransactionViewModel.Tags` in `VM.Transactions`.